# For which $n$ is $\mathbb{Z}_2$ a $\mathbb{Z}_n$-module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

> Determine the values ​​of $n$ for which $\mathbb{Z}_2$  is a $\mathbb{Z}_n$-module (with action given by "the product $\mathbb{Z}_2$").

If $n=2k+1,$ $k\geq 1$, then:

\begin{align*}
0=0_{\mathbb{Z}_n}*1=n*1=(2k+1)*1\neq 2(k*1)+1*1=0+1=1
\end{align*}

But if $n=2k$ , $k>1$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Giving a module action on $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is easily seen to be equivalent as giving a ring homomorphism
$$
\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\to
\hom(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})
$$
and the codomain, as a ring, is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. Such a homomorphism must be surjective, because $1\mapsto 1$.

Can such a homomorphism exist if $n$ is odd?

If $n$ is even, so $n=2m$, the ring $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ has the ideal $m\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ and the quotient is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ as rings.